# How to dyanmically pass the sessionFactory to <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sftp

How to dynamically pass the sessionFactory to sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

Case : We want to write a generic utility which will download a file from different SFTP Servers.
if user one wants to download a file from SFTPSERVER1 we have to pass SFTPSERVER1 details to session Factory.
if user2  wants to download a file from SFTPSERVER2 we have to pass SFTPSERVER2 details to session Factory.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Adapter Creation is something what you are looking for. These links from Spring Board might help:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/128268-creating-ftp-sftp-inbound-channel-adapter-programmatically

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/119081-dynamic-inbound-channel-adapter-creation